# Why does doing pushups feel more exhaustive than pulling racks?

Tags: strength, gym, push-ups

For example some people in prison complain than they have to resort to push-ups in order to keep in shape, if they don't have access to gym equipment

I guess I'm trying to understand why do some tools make it easier for us to gain strength vs just using our body to gain the same amount of strength?

Answer (score 2):

External tools provide a simple method to apply greater resistance.